# Show that $u-v=\sqrt5$ given that $u-v>0$ given that $u=b+b^4$ and $v=b^2+b^3$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

We're also given that $b$ is a root of $z^5-1=0$ $b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1=0$
If $u=b+b^4$ and $v=b^2+b^3$, show that

i) $u+v=uv=-1$

ii) $u-v=\sqrt5$ given that $u-v>0$

I managed to do part i):

Plugging in $u$ and $v$: $(b+b^4)+(b^2+b^3)=-1$ (using $b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1=0$)

$uv=(b+b^4)(b^2+b^3)$
$=(b^3+b^4+b^6+b^7)$
$=b^3(1+b+b3+b4)$
$=b^3(-b^2)$
$=-b^5$
$=-1^5$
$=-1$ (using $z^5=1$)

For ii)

$u-v=(b+b^4)-(b^2+b3)>0$

$(b+b^4)-(-b-b^4-1)>0$

$2b+2b^4+1>0$

$b+b^4>\frac{-1}{2}$

Although it's a dead-end after that.

What's the general idea for going about solving part ii)?

Comment: Hint: Try computing $(u-v)^2$ which is symmetric in $u$ and $v$

Answer (score 2):

Just compute
$$
(u-v)^2=(b+b^4-b^2-b^3)^2=-(b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1)+5=5.
$$
We have used $b^5=1$ in the second step.

Answer (score 1):

One approach: the quadratic equation $(x-u)(x-v) = 0$ which has roots $u$ and $v$ expands to $x^2 - (u+v)x + uv = 0$. Once you've computed $u+v = uv = -1$, you know that this is the quadratic equation $x^2 + x - 1 = 0$, which you can just solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute $(u-v)^2=(u+v)^2-4uv$ simply from what you already know.

You have the elementary symmetric polynomials and $(u-v)^2$ is symmetric, so it will have an expression in terms of $uv$ and $u+v$. The computation is equivalent to solving the quadratic with roots $u$ and $v$, but is more straightforward - you don't need to go via the quadratic.

Comment: Note: this method explains why the first step is useful progress.